# Is there another way to match the MAC and IP Addresses in VB.NET 2008 besides using WMI?

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, network-programming

I would like to match multiple network card MAC's with the corresponding IP Addresses to be displayed.  Is there a better (or just another) way to enumerate them besides using System.Management or out-and-out WMI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could P/Invoke [GetAdaptersAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365915%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) in the IP Helper API. This returns you a list of [IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES structures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366058%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) that include the IP Addresses and MAC info (in `PhysicalAddress`) for each adapter.

Non-trivial marshalling - fortunately [PInvoke.Net](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi.GetAdaptersAddresses) has it down.

Comment: That's some great stuff!  Will it work with WinXP through Win7?  I worry that there will be changes in the DLL.

Comment: Per the MSDN page for the function it's good for WinXP and WinSrv 2003 on up.  All the best.